# can i use google spread sheets instead of firebase for my app

Tags: firebase, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a doubt which is can i use spread sheet as a database for my flutter android app. Currently i'm using firebase. If yes then what is advantage and disadvantage ?? Pls tell me if anyone know. Answer would be help me a lot.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use many online data storage options but you will find each has its own pro's and con's many that hinder or outright block usage in some situations.

Google spreadsheets have limits of 500 requests per 100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user. Limits for reads and writes are tracked separately.
And I couldn't guarantee it's a solid solution without stress test examples, so use with caution.